# Mailto links on websites open iTerm instead of Mail

Tags: terminal, safari, mail.app, google-chrome, iterm

In both Chrome and Safari `mailto:` links open up **iTerm** instead of **Mail**.

This seemed to have started happening right around the same time I added a shortcut through *Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts* to use `command+enter` to *Send* in the Mail app.

But I have no idea if that has anything to do with this problem, or where else to even begin looking.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the default Mail application, via **Mail.app** Preferences.

It is underneath the "**General**" settings, as "**Default email reader**".

Even if Mail.app appears to be already selected it might be worth a shot to select something else, then go back to Mail.app in order to clear the cobwebs.

Comment: You nailed it! No idea how or why it got set to iTerm but changing it back to mail.app fixed it :-)

Comment: This didn't fix it for me, it simply reverts back to iTerm2 :/

Comment: You should make a new question, with your situation. The solution likely involves file permissions but you can supply more details in your own question.

Comment: Q:Does this still work in Safari 13?  A:Yes.